# 関わらず, こうして, and "Titles"

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

My question concerns the middle part of this sentence.

> 宮さんは、**僕がこうして敬称付きで呼ぶにも関わらず**、  見た目十代前半くらいの少女なのだった。

1. How exactly does こうして affect the meaning of the sentence?
2. What part of the sentence is 関わらず talking about? Regardless of the title? Of an invitation?
3. If 敬称付きで means something like "has the title of" then how is what comes after (呼ぶ) to be interpreted? I assume it has to be either "invited" or "inviter." Can it be either?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: 呼ぶ here does not mean "invite".

Comment: Really? Because other definitions would sound strange, unless it is "summoner/summoned" but that sounds too much like fantasy. I can't imagine it means "caller/called." Is it just saying "Has been given a title" and it leaves it at that?

Comment: I'm not sure what dictionary you're using, but "summoner/summoned" and "caller/called" don't look like very good definitions for 呼ぶ.  (It's a verb!)  Perhaps you could try another dictionary: [こうして](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=3&dname=2ss&p=%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) - [よぶ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=3&dname=2ss&p=%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B6) - [かかわらず](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=2&dtype=3&dname=2ss&p=%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A)

Comment: I know it's a verb (to summon/to call/to invite). I figured something was nominalizing it, but I realize now it was probably just a verb modifying 敬称付きで

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can tell from the given sentence:

1. 「こうして」 is simply a way for the speaker to explain to the listener that the speaker added some sort of honorific title ***in this way*** to the person the speaker was addressing.
2. 「にも関{かか}わらず」then refers to how the speaker is explaining to the listener how the speaker was using some sort of honorific title for 宮さん *(typically meant for someone older or more respected,)* because the speaker had possibly been thinking *(up until this particular point in time)* that 宮さん was actually an older person... until finally meeting 宮さん in person, when the speaker sees that 宮さん actually looks more like a young girl... *which is why it is ironic that the speaker would be using some sort of honorific title when addressing 宮さん.*
3. 「敬称付{けいしょうつ}き」goes back to how the speaker is talking about how the speaker added an honorific title to the person the speaker was addressing.  (And as @dainichi mentioned earlier, I don't see where the "inviter" or "invited" part would come in to play, in the case of the given sentence.)

It sounds like the main point of this sentence *(from the speaker's point of view)* is something like:

> Miya-san appeared to be like a young girl, *even though* I had been *addressing* her *in this sort of way*.

Comment: I'm not sure, because I'm not the one who downvoted you (dont have enough rep to, anyway), but I'm really confused, because is there even a reference to a customer in that sentence..? On the other hand, I didn't think it could be about the honorific, but it could be, so at least you helped the asker a bit. I'll upvote you back to 0 if for nothing else.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks for the catch about the name; my eyes are going bad...

Comment: @user3538 Sorry about the misreading earlier... I don't think this sentence was about a customer after all ^^  Edited answer to reflect changes...

Comment: Oh sorry, I could have told you it was a name :/ Anyway now that the answer is completely correct (if I'm not mistaken), I think that one downvote should be removed. Thank you both, I understand this better now :)

Comment: About 2., its actually the other way around: "although I had been adressing her with a title, she was a young girl", or maybe even "she turned out to be a young girl". Presumably her the speaker met her for the first time, having only communicated with her in writing previously.

Comment: @dainichi Thank you; after the earlier changes, I forgot to go back and make that edit... ^^;